# Can I wear the Freddy mask forever?

Tags: five-nights-at-freddys-2

I've been testing a theory if I can wear the Freddy mask forever and just crank up the marionette box when I need to. Do you guys think it would work if I had this menu?

[image]

I've looked it up before, but it doesn't say anything if it works or not. It always says something about Foxy or marionette but I will crank up the music box. And as you can see I'll turn off Foxy's character. So do you think that'll work or not? Thank you!

Comment: You cannot crank the box while wearing the mask.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does wearing the Freddy Fazbear Mask do?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191312/what-does-wearing-the-freddy-fazbear-mask-do)

Comment: You technically already have your answer - it is impossible to wear the mask *forever* since you have to remove it to crank up the music box.

Comment: yes but it is I crank up music put it back on technically I can